# How to make Android WebView Cache to have application scope

Tags: android, caching, webview

Say I have an Application with an Activity A with a Web-view A and an Activity B with a Web-view B. Activity A is the launcher activity and the transition is A->B.

Both the web-view needs to download Java-script files during URL Loading. To avoid re-download the file every time, I used setEnableCache(true) and that didn't seem to work as on transition from activity A to activity B, the web-view cache is cleared.

How can I avoid Web-view cache to be cleared on activity transition?

or in other way, how can I make all web-views used in different activities in my application to reuse the same cache.

Comment: Have you ever tried creating a base class that enables caching and other activity classes(A,B) extend this base class?

Comment: AFAIK the cache is shared between WebViews by default. Maybe the server is setting a 'Cache-Control': 'no-store'?

Comment: @marcin.kosiba You are right, It is shared among all the activities. The problem was from the server side, problem solved now.

Comment: @marcin.kosiba Do you know if it is possible to manually add some files to the cache somehow? I want to make the web-view use some big javascript files directly from the cache instead of downloading it, even at the first time it has been started.

Comment: @sumit - I don't think there is a direct API for that. The underlying DB format can change too, so don't fiddle with that. You could use shouldInterceptRequest to intercept the GET for the .js and provide the data yourself.